# User prompt in C

Tags: c, prompt

So I have this code and it is not working quite like I want it to. Basically it should prompt the user repeatedly then the user will input a command and argument(s). The program will then respond with "Command Entered" and then the first word entered. Then "Arguments entered" with the 2nd word and all the words after that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char mychar[30];
  char arg[30];
while(1)
{
    printf("G- ");
    fgets (mychar, 100, stdin);
    fgets (arg, 100, stdin);
    printf("Command entered: %s", mychar); 
    printf("Arguments entered: %s", arg);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use fscanf() instead of fgets() in first place.

```
int main()
{
  char mychar[30];
  char arg[30];
while(1)
{
    printf("Grock- ");
    fscanf (stdin, "%s", mychar);
    fgets (arg, 100, stdin);
    printf("Command entered: %s\n", mychar); 
    printf("Arguments entered: %s\n", arg);

}
}
```

fscanf() will take the first param as "command" and all the rest as "argument" for that purpose fgets() is okay.

Comment: that works good except it doesn't work when the command is just an enter. Any ideas?

Comment: Then it's better to check the return value of fscanf(), and handle the case, the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

After read using `fgets()`, use `sscanf()` to parse.

`"%9s"` Skip leading whitespace, scan and save up to 9 non-whitespace char.  Append \0.
`" "`  Skip white space.
`"%29[^\n]"`  Do not skip leading whitespace.  Scan and save up to 29 char, up to end of string or a `\n`.  Append \0.

```
while(1) {
  printf("Grock- ");
  // fgets(mychar, 100, stdin);  // 100 is bad: see mychar[30]
  if (NULL == fgets(mychar, sizeof(mychar), stdin)) break;
  char command[10];
  char args[30];
  if (2 != sscanf(mychar, "%9s %29[^\n]", command, args)) {
    ; // handle error
  }
  printf("Command entered: '%s'", command); 
  printf("Arguments entered: '%s'", args);
}
```